# Vlookup with specific date showing N/A

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to apply vllokup for a specific month of a specific year. My formula works for string lookup value but not works for date. here I attached my effort

[image: Excel work]

Comment: What value do you have in `D4` cell? It is string or true date value formatted `mmm yyyy`.

Comment: D4 : 1/1/2022 .........  C6 : 1/1/2022

Comment: See my answer. You have to use `index/match` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `VLOOKUP()` will not work in this case because `VLOOKUP()` always lookup values on first column of table then return value from corresponding row from specified column. So, you first column is strings and vlookup do not find dates on first column. Use `Index/Match` instead.

```
=INDEX(B3:B5,MATCH(D1,C3:C5,0))
```

You can also use `FILTER()` function.

```
=FILTER(B3:B5,C3:C5=D1)
```

`Query()` will also work-

```
=QUERY(B3:C,"select B where C= date '" & text(D1,"yyyy-mm-dd") & "'")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but showing N/A

Comment: @kashfiq can you share the sample workbook so that I can check.

Comment: Please find file download link  we.tl/t-bocOQgnsYw

Comment: @kashfiq Use exact this formula to your demo file. `=INDEX($B$5:$B$7,MATCH($D$4,$C$5:$C$7))`.

Comment: `=INDEX(B5:B7,MATCH(D4,C5:C7))`

Comment: Showing ERROR....

Comment: @kashfiq It must work. Based on regional settings you may have to use `;` instead of comma `,`. Then formula would be `=INDEX(B5:B7;MATCH(D4;C5:C7;0))` or may be missed last part of match formula try- `=INDEX(B5:B7,MATCH(D4,C5:C7,0))`

Comment: @kashfiq Such an error 95% of the time comes from either forgetting last parameter (0) on the match or value mismatch (text vs date; Jan 1st vs 2nd; text vs untrimmed text).

Answer (score 1):

`Vlookup` works by searching columns to the left of the searched column. So you should modify your sheet to look like this (if possible) :

[image]

However, you should also take into account that the formatting of your cells could be misleading. If your `D4`cell has the value 1/Jan/2022 and your `C6` cell has the value of 2/Jan/2022, then both of them will show as `Jan 2022`, but your formula will still return `N/A` because the real values of the cells are different.